# Plot markers by JSON format

Tags: arrays, json, swift

This is my JSON data I want plot it on map

JSON

```
{        
    result = (
        {
            "geo_x" = "18.956092";
            "geo_y" = "72.811876";
        }
    );
}
```

My Swift Code is ,

```
let data = JSON as! Dictionary
let result = data["result"] as! NSArray
let geox = result.valueForKey("geo_x") as! NSArray //Here I'm storing all geox getting from JSON
let geoy = result.valueForKey("geo_y") as! NSArray //Here I'm storing all geoy getting from JSON
let count = geox.count //count of array
for index in 0...count {
    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(geox(index),geoy(index))
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: What is the problem that you want help with?

Comment: Are you sure that `result.valueForKey("geo_x")` is a `NSArray`? In your sample it isn't. And you didn't say what's exactly wrong with your current code.

Comment: it's an array thanks Larme and Anton Bronnikov